# using conditional awk statement to control regex pattern

Tags: awk

I have code that parses through a csv file and then checks each field against a regex. however there are a few fields that need to be mandatory if another field has data in it, so I essentially need a conditional block to control the flow of data . so for example of sample file see below

```
 "S","HEY","J","B","0",""
```

so what I need is a way to say

```
if $1 == "S"
USE THIS regex ($3~/^("[A-Z0-9]{1}")$/) {print "3RDfield invalid-HEADER-FILE";}
else 
USE THIS REGEX ($3~/^("")$/) {print "3RDfield invalid-HEADER-FILE";}
```

I have tried using inline version

```
$1== "S" && ($3~/^"[A-Z0-9]{1}"$/) {print "3RD field invalid-HEADER-      FILE";}  
$1 != "S" && ($3~/^("")$/) {print "3RDfield invalid-HEADER-FILE";}
```

Comment: Why not `$1 != "S" && ($5~/^("")$/)` for that second block?  That's what you initially described.

Comment: That should be `$1=="\"S\"" && ..`, `$44!="\"B\"" && ..`, right? (otherwise it will match `S,...` (an unquoted `S` as `$1`).

Comment: @Kusalananda apologies I copied the wrong segment of code see post for correct version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {
   if ($1 == "\"S\"")
     regex = "^\"[[:upper:][:digit:]]\"$"
   else
     regex = "^\"\"$"
 }
 $5 ~ regex {print "error"}
```

Or using the ternary operator:

```
 $5 ~ ($1 == "\"S\"" ? "^\"[[:upper:][:digit:]]\"$" : "^\"\"$") {
   print "error"
 }
```

Note that `[A-Z]`, `[0-9]` could (and in practice sometimes do) match just about anything in locales other than C, while `[[:digit:]]` matches `[0123456789]` and `[[:upper:]]`  uppercase letters (all the ones in the locale, not necessarily limited to latin ones without diacritics).

`{1}` is superfluous.

Comment: unfortunately due to the system this will be implemented on it doesn't have posix  support so [[:upper:]] and the like wont work on the system hence the older a-z method

Comment: and yes you are correct about {1} I have now removed it

Comment: @jordanb111, OK. If it doesn't support POSIX character classes, chances are it won't support `{1}` either (superfluous anyway). If `[A-Z]` matches other characters than `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, you can always replace it with `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]` or fix the locale to `C`.

Comment: in my testing it hasn't matched any other characters but I will continue and see if it matches anything else

Comment: @jordanb111, in a locale using the UTF-8 charset, you can do `perl -XCO -le 'print chr($_) for  0x1..0xd7ff,0xe000..0x10ffff' | awk '/^[A-Z]$/'` to find the single-character collating elements that `[A-Z]` matches (it may also match multi-character collating elements like Hungarian `Dzs`). For `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` on Solaris, I get 1205 characters, including `b-z`

Comment: right ok that's good to know i'll swap over to literal then thanks

Comment: also if I wanted to change "\"S\"" to match say M N and S how would I go about doing that

Comment: @jordanb111, `regex = "^\"[MNS]\"$"`